# Jenkins with Subversion is best to export?

Tags: java, jenkins, svn, building, svn-checkout

when building a project with Jenkins and Subversion,
 
is it better to use the **checkout** command or to use **export**?

I know checkout, will give you a working copy and and you can use the commit and update commands of Subversion (later if needed) and you also get the .svn folders. And by using export, Subversion simply fetches a copy of the project (and no .svn folders).

What's the best practice for building a project?

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 8):

use checkout and option "emulate clean checkout".

If you use export, then, you'll do a full checkout of your project at each build, slowing things down, and putting more load on your SVN server.

Answer (score 3):

`svn checkout` is notoriously inefficient and slow.

If Jenkins is doing a build for the purposes of checking for compilation errors, and/or running unit tests, one will never need to make any further SVN changes.  Hence `svn export` should certainly be used in such cases.  One should prefer `svn export` *especially* as it is roughly 6 times faster[1] than `svn checkout`.  It also results in a disk space consumption of roughly half that of a checkout.

I'm baffled as to why Jenkins does not provide `svn export` as a standard option.

[1] In a sample repo at my employer, `checkout` takes 12 - 13 minutes, and `export` less than 2 minutes.  The size of the resulting export is 343MB; the size of a checkout is about 646MB.